# Video performance on a Lenovo T520 is slow

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, performance, nvidia-optimus

I have a new Lenovo t520 with 8gb memory and a i7 cpu. It's the first time I 'really' install Ubuntu on a pc. I have about six months of experience with Ubuntu as a guest OS on Windows in a VM.

Now what is really annoying me is how slow the visuals are on my laptop. Mostly noticeable when I have to resize or move a window. Also when scrolling text in vim/browsers it's not really as smooth as I would like it.

I read that Lenovo is using Optimus drivers for their new laptops and that these aren't supported. So I was wondering could using the integrated Intel gpu be the problem?

The CPU I have is the Core™ i7-2620M (2.70GHz, 4MB L3, 1333MHz FSB). I have tried to enable desktop effects but that didn't work.

Comment: Integrated GPU on new laptop are powerful enough to have good performance (if you're not planning to play 3d games).
I have optimus on Asus 1215n and my nvidia card is not working.
The intel handles everything and does it with smoothness.
I think you just need to investigate about installing correctly your main card drivers :)

Comment: The discrete card is Nvidia NVS 4200M (1GB VRAM) with Optimus. The processor is either i7-2820QM, i7-2720QM or i7-2630QM (taken from [this datasheet](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/ww/pdf/t420_t520_datasheet.pdf).)

Comment: @Pitto: agreed, for general tasks it suffice. I've an i5-460M with a GT 425M and I can use all desktop effects.

Comment: So it might be that the integrated GPU isn't installed corrently? The CPU I have is the Core™ i7-2620M (2.70GHz, 4MB L3, 1333MHz FSB)

Comment: I do believe so, my friend...
Can you enable desktop effects?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. It also might be that I don't have an Nvidia card after all can't find anything about it in my Windows dual boot. I assumed all Lenovo laptops had one. Is there a way to find out which Intel Integrated HD card/type I have?

Comment: It seems that I need support for Sandy Bridge which if I read correctly is coming in 11.04.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the bumblebee solution in this page:
https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux
You will be able to use both the intel card for the desktop and the nvidia card for specific applications. Check the google-chrome FPS values for benchmarking:

```
sudo apt-get install git
# type password
git clone http://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee.git
cd bumblebee/
sudo ./install.sh
optirun glxgears
# check the speed and compare to running:
glxgears
# If you have google-chrome installed, you can try it with/without optirun and report the FPS values on the mailing list:
optirun google-chrome http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html
```

Comment: These instructions (and the one for Bumblebee at hybrid-graphics-linux) are outdated, please see http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969

Comment: Can you update the instructions? Installing this from git is not recommended and the repo is broken anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The integrated GPU does indeed have worse performance compared to a discrete one. NVidia Optimus is completly unsupported in Ubuntu. If you're lucky, there might be a BIOS switch to switch between the discrete graphic card (nvidia) an the integrated GPU (i7).

Comment: There is now relatively good support with bumblebee: http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

Comment: Yes, there is a BIOS switch to control what graphics hardware should be enabled on Lenovo laptops.